# See which component in regex alternation was captured

Tags: python, regex

In regex alternation, is there a way to retrieve which alternation was matched? I just need the first alternation match, not all the alternations that match.

For example, I have a regex like this

```
pattern = r'(abc.*def|mno.*pqr|mno.*pqrt|.....)'
string = 'mnoxxxpqrt'
```

I want the output to be `'mno.*pqr'`

How should I write the regex statement? Python language is preferred.

Comment: Your regex doesn't make sense. `mno.*pqrt` will never match, since `mno.*pqr` would've matched instead.

Comment: I know, that is the point I am making, I only want the first match, not all matches, so I don't want ```mno.*pqrt``` to be returned.

Comment: But why did you even include that in the regex?

Comment: to show that I dont want it to be returned. For example, the answer by Tim Biegeleisen https://stackoverflow.com/a/75368815/4532333 for my original question would return mno.*pqrt.

Comment: Hmm, I might've changed `string` instead to make that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this efficiently without any iterations, you can put your desired sub-patterns in a list and join them into one alternation pattern with each sub-pattern enclosed in a capture group (so the resulting pattern looks like `(abc.*def)|(mno.*pqr)` instead of `(abc.*def|mno.*pqr)`). You can then obtain the group number of the sub-pattern with the `Match` object's [`lastindex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.lastindex) attribute and in turn obtain the matching sub-pattern from the original list of sub-patterns:

```
import re

patterns = [r'abc.*def', r'mno.*pqr', r'mno.*pqrt']
pattern = '|'.join(map('({})'.format, patterns))
string = 'mno_foobar_pqrt'
print(pattern)
print(patterns[re.search(pattern, string).lastindex - 1])
```

This outputs:

```
(abc.*def)|(mno.*pqr)|(mno.*pqrt)
mno.*pqr
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/JointBruisedMention

Answer (score 1):

You can use capture groups:

```
import re
string = 'abcxxxdef'
patterns = ['abc.*def', 'mno.*pqr']
match = re.match(r'((abc.*def)|(mno.*pqr))',string)
groups = match.groups()
alternations = []
for i in range(1, len(groups)):
    if (groups[i] != None):
        pattern = patterns[i-1]
        break
print(pattern)
```

Result: `mno.*pqr`

Expressions inside round brackets are capture groups, they correspond to the 1st to last index of the response. The 0th index is the whole match.

Then you would need to find the index which matched. Except your patterns would need to be fined before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could iterate the terms in the regex alternation:

```py
string = 'abcxxxdef'
pattern = r'(abc.*def|mno.*pqr)'
terms = pattern[1:-1].split("|")
for term in terms:
    if re.search(term, string):
        print("MATCH => " + term)
```

This prints:

```
MATCH => abc.*def
```

Comment: This is an exhaustive iteration. For my problem, performance is important, so I prefer not to use loop, but want to take use of the optimization inside the regex engine.
If I have 100s or 1000s of patterns, looping will take too long.

Comment: I think more importantly, this isn't equivalent. It prefers earlier patterns instead of earlier matches. If you think of them as two nested loops, this swapped the two loops.

Comment: @KellyBundy Not following you.  A regex alternation certainly is ordered, and matches left to right.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For example on the string "mnoabcpqrdef", they match with `mno.*pqr`, but you match with `abc.*def` (first).

Answer (score 0):

The right answer to the question *How should I write the regex statement?* should actually be:

**There is no known way to write the regex statement using the provided regex pattern which will allow to extract from the regex search result the information which of the alternatives have triggered the match.**

And as there is no way to do it using the given pattern it is necessary to change the regex pattern which then makes it possible to extract from the match the requested information.

A possible way around this regex engine limitation is proposed below, but it requires an additional regex pattern search and has the disadvantage that there is a chance that it fails for some special search pattern alternatives.

The below provided code allows usage of simpler regex patterns without defining groups and works the "other way around" by checking which of the alternate patterns triggers a match in the found match for the entire regex:

```
import re
pattern = r'abc.*def|mno.*pqr|mno.*pqrt'
text    = 'mnoxxxpqrt'
match   = re.match(pattern,text)[0]
print(next(p for p in pattern.split('|') if re.match(p, match)))
```

It might fail in case when in the text found match string fails to be also a match for the single regex pattern what can happen for example if a non-word boundary `\B` requirement is used in the search pattern ( as mentioned in the comments by *Kelly Bundy* ).

---

A not failing alternative solution is to perform the regex search using a modified regex pattern. Below an approach using a dictionary for defining the alternatives and a function returning the matched group:

```
import re

dct_alts = {1:r'(abc.*def)',2:r'(mno.*pqr)',3:r'(mno.*pqrt)'}
#           ^-- the dictionary index  is the index of the matching group in the found match. 

text     = 'mnoxxxpqrt'
    
def get_matched_group(dct_alts, text):
    pattern  = '|'.join(dct_alts.values())
    re_match = re.match(pattern, text) 
    return(dct_alts[re_match.lastindex])

print(get_matched_group(dct_alts, text))
```

prints

```
(mno.*pqr)
```

For the sake of completeness a function returning a list of all of the  alternatives which give a match (not only the first one which matches):

```
import re
lst_alts = [r'abc.*def', r'mno.*pqr', r'mno.*pqrt']
text     = 'mnoxxxpqrt'
def get_all_matched_groups(lst_alts, text):
    matches = []
    for pattern in lst_alts: 
        re_match = re.match(pattern, text) 
        if re_match:
            matches.append(pattern)
    return matches
print(get_all_matched_groups(lst_alts, text))
```

prints

```
['mno.*pqr', 'mno.*pqrt']
```

Comment: How to get the matched string out of a match if not by [0]? `match` is maybe not a well chosen variable name for the in the text found string. How can that solution fail? Can't imagine how it could be.

Comment: I was talking about building the list, so I meant the other [0]. The one you use to throw away the rest of the list.

Comment: [Demo](https://tio.run/##VYwxDsIwDEX3nMKbk6qKkFhYunCN0iGUVI1EE2M8BKl3D2npghfrP/t9@sic4vlCXEpYKLEAe0VOxHOEDhjdfbTNw0/rEpNt6MW3KyrxWaBOB1hxzrlyQbU4Gecds7d70EdVuxmmPw2KOETR@9Ecoa9PMCWGbYcIh2Pf9AyicUUDYfqrbH/@UAtNKV8) of the failure I mentioned.

Comment: The one-liner makes not much sense so I have removed it from the answer. And yes, the the simple solution not changing the regex pattern could fail - thanks for pointing it out.